# Question in ergodic theory

Tags: analysis, probability-theory

Again the source is http://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/275c.1.13s/PDFs/HW1.pdf this time I'm looking at #6 the part that is left as an open-ended question.  If $f \in L^1$ and $\phi$ is a measure preserving map, then we already know that

$1/n*\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f*e^{ik\xi}$ [1]

converges a.s. for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$.  But can I find one a.s. set on which the convergence occurs at the same time for all $\xi$?  I really don't want to get into my attempt to prove a counterexample too much, because it was extremely complicated and failed.  Suffice it to say I tried to consider the completion of the measure space $([0, 1)^\mathbb{R}, Borel, Lebesgue^\mathbb{R})$

I solved the first part by taking a cross product with the unit circle and modifying my maps so as to squeeze out the result.  Turns out that if you take the product with the unit circle twice and again do things appropriately, you can deduce that there exists a measure 1 set in your probability space and a lebesgue a.e. set of $\xi$ such that you have simultaneous convergence of [1] for all the $\xi$ on your measure 1 set.  Too bad it's not quite literally everywhere.  Even this measure 0 set seems to be problematic.  If it was countable, I'd be done.  A friend and I tried to go about this by tricks like considering instead the countable-cocountable sigma algebra, and a variety of other tricks, none working so far.

Is it true or false?  How do I show that?  On this problem I have basically exhausted everything, so I would not consider it a bad thing if a solution or very strong hint were basically given to me at this point.